Нужно добавить простую капчу от ботов в форму обратной связи
Подскажите, как добавить простую капчу от ботов в такую форму обратной связи?
Делал на подобии "Решите пример", 25+5 = проверка textarea = 30, тогда кнопка доступна для отправки формы. Боты все равно ее заполняют правильно. Есть ли какая-то более защищенная капча, но не от google и с простой установкой?
Код html
 <form action="contact.php" id="contact-form" method="POST">
                            <div class="row g-4">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-clt">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Полное имя">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-clt">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder=" Эл. адрес">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-clt-big form-clt">
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Пишите Комментарии"></textarea>
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="fal fa-pencil"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            
            <button type="submit" class="theme-btn"><ya-tr-span data-index="39-0" data-translated="true" data-source-lang="en" data-target-lang="ru" data-value="Send Message" data-translation="Отправить сообщение" data-ch="0" data-type="trSpan" style="visibility: inherit !important;">Отправить сообщение</ya-tr-span><i class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <p class="form-message"></p>

Код php
<?php
    /*
    name
    email
    message
    */
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "ПОЧТА";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email \n$message\n";
        $email_content .= "Message \n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient,  $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong ande we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>


Капчи - против людей, а не против ботов. Против ботов есть методы/алгоритмы.

Капчи как раз против ботов.

Согласен, потому что приходят сообщения как раз от ботов

Не понял, а где здесь проверка-то? И что такое "проверка textarea"? Так-то я бы предложил писать числа прописью. Если не спец-бот конкретно для этой формы, то вряд ли будет считать. С другой стороны, если бот с аи, то даже не заметит эту капчу. Ну сделайте горшок с мёдом, поле с заголовком "Не заполнять" и name="subject".

Я его убрал, потому что плохо работал. Стало ботов существенно меньше, но всеравно проскакивали..

Ну так возможно дело не в капче, а в реализации. Вы хоть сессию-то использовали?

@u111 тебя обманули.

@YelloSOFT "Согласен, потому что приходят сообщения как раз от ботов". Неужели ты ожидал от инопланетян? Удивительно было бы если бы боты не спамили в форму :) Если интересует конверсия (если знаешь что это такое), то никогда не используй капчи. Есть более правильные методы отсеивать ботов.

@SeVlad, ты говоришь только об "правильности", но ни одного примера так не привел. И вопрос в теме стоит "КАК ДОБАВИТЬ ПРОСТУЮ КАПЧУ", а не "КАК ЗАЩИТИТЬСЯ ОТ СПАМА". Легко быть диванным "экспертом".

@YelloSOFT, вот именно - ты не спрашивал "как правильно". Ты решил что тебе надо капча. Типичная ошибка молотка. Но бывай, недиванный икпрерт.

@SeVlad, снова только вода и 0 примеров по факту. Слово "Эксперт", пишется через "Э", если тебе не известны методы/алгоритмы Русского языка. Ступай.

Однажды у меня сработала защита от дурака: генерировал строчку текста, добавлял поле для ввода и подписывал - введите что угодно, но только не то, что написано. Боты принципиально вводили в поле сгенерированное значение и пролетали.

function hundred2text($num) {
    $teens = ['ноль','один','два','три','четыре','пять','шесть','семь', 'восемь','девять', 
              'десять','одиннадцать','двенадцать','тринадцать', 'четырнадцать','пятнадцать',
              'шестнадцать','семнадцать', 'восемнадцать','девятнадцать','двадцать'];
    $tens =  [2 => 'двадцать','тридцать','сорок','пятьдесят', 'шестьдесят','семьдесят','восемьдесят','девяносто'];

    if ($num < 21) {
        return $teens[$num];
    } else {
        $num = (string)$num;
        return $tens[$num[0]] . ( $num[1] ? " " . $teens[$num[1]] : "");
    }
}

$first = random_int(0,99);
$second = random_int(0,99);
$text = hundred2text($first) . " плюс " . hundred2text($second);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $first + $second;

В форме показываем $text, просим ввести результат.
В обработчике сравниваем введенный результат и обнуляем $_SESSION['captcha'].
